# How to make query “or” instead of “and” with meteor.js(mongodb)?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Users can filter cards based on what kind of filter they select.

But currently instead of “or”, I get a result as "and".

Here is an example.

```
{
  '_id':'111111111111',
  'title':'This is a title',
  'description': 'Description',
  assigned:true,
  leader:false,
  public:true
}

{
  '_id':'222222222222',
  'title':'apple',
  'description': 'banana',
  assigned : false,
  leader : false,
  public : true
}

{
  '_id':'33333333333333',
  'title':'lemon',
  'description': 'hello',
  assigned:false,
  leader:true,
  public:false
}
```

And user wants to get cards that have `assigned: true` OR `leader: false` which this case `_id : ''111111111111"` and `_id : "33333333333333"`.

What would be the query for this look like?

When I console my query it looks like this and this will fetch cards that have `assigned: true` AND `leader: false`.

```
{
    assigned: true,
    leader: false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CollectionName.find({$or: [{assigned: true}, {leader: false}]})
```

- https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#selectors
- https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#mongodb-query-op.-or